# Need to add formatting to a string reduced to x significant figures

Tags: python, arrays, string, formatting

I need to format a text file, but some values (required to 6SF) are out of line with the rest of the document. See below:

```
import numpy as np     
A1=np.linspace(1., 10**15., 1000)
f = open('document.txt', 'w')
f.write('Document of values' + "\n")
f.write('Column 1' + "\t" + "\t" + 'Column 2' + "\t" + 'Column 3' + "\n")
for i in range(len(A1)):
    f.write(str("%.6g" % A1[i]) + "\t " + "\t" + str("%.6g" % A1[i]) + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + str("%.6g" % A1[i]) +"\n")
f.close()
```

Currently I am attempting something along the lines of this:

```
import numpy as np  
A1=np.linspace(1., 10**15., 1000)
A2=str(A1)
A3=str(A1)
for i in range(len(A2)):
    if 'e' in A2[i]:
        A3[i]=("%.6g" % A2[i])
    else:
        A3[i]=(("%.6g" % A2[i]) + "\t")

f = open('document.txt', 'w')
f.write('Document of values' + "\n")
f.write('Column 1' + "\t" + 'Column 2' + "\t" + 'Column 3' + "\n")
for i in range(len(A1)):
    f.write(str(A3[i]) + "\t" + "\t" + str("%.6g" % A1[i]) + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + str("%.6g" % A1[i]) +"\n")
f.close()
```

In order to add an additional `/t` to the values in column 1 that don't have an `e+xx` value in them. The output must be in a .txt file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You do realize that a `\t` has no defined stardard width?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. What exactly is the objective for us to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that you need to separate your numbers with tabs?

Tabs looks different in different text editors (sometimes tab = 4 spaces, sometimes it's 2, and sometimes it's 8)

With plain spaces you can easilly achieve what you want.

Just pad your numbers with spaces to the desired length.

You aready have formating for part of the strings, you just need to use ljust or rjust string function:

`("%.6g" % x).rjust(8)` - will always give your 8-characters string, for x = 0 or for x = 999999.999999

So, combine this constructions for columns, that you need to build and you'll be ok!